# Variadic template compilation issue on MS Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, variadic-templates

I need a template to find out the order of types in which the class inherits from its bases and their index. The code works fine with clang and gcc but in Visual Studio, which is the target environment, I'm getting an internal compiler error "fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.". I'm looking for some workaround or maybe an error in my code. Yes, I have already tried google.

Thanks, in advance.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct BaseA
{
};

struct BaseB
{
};

struct BaseC
{
};

template <class... Types>
class type_list {};

template<typename Type, typename TypeList>
struct get_idx_for_type;

template<typename Type, template<typename...> typename TypeList, typename ...Types>
struct get_idx_for_type<Type, TypeList<Types...>>
{
    template<int I, typename T, typename ...Rest>
    struct find_type;

    template<int I, typename T, typename U, typename ...Rest>
    struct find_type< I, T, U, Rest... >
    {
        // problematic line for compiler, problem is somewhere in find_type recursion
        static constexpr int value = std::is_same<T, U>::value ? I : find_type<I + 1, T, Rest...>::value;
    };

    template<int I, typename T, typename U>
    struct find_type< I, T, U >
    {
        static constexpr int value = std::is_same<T, U>::value ? I : -1;
    };

    static constexpr int value = find_type<0, Type, Types...>::value;
};

template<typename ...Bases>
struct Foo : public Bases...
{
    using base_types_list = type_list<Bases...>;
};

int main()
{
    using T = Foo<BaseA, BaseB, BaseC>;
    Foo<BaseA, BaseB, BaseC> q;

    int a = get_idx_for_type<BaseA, T::base_types_list>::value;

    std::cout << a << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you are using the latest version of visual studio I'd suggest following the instructions in the error message to submit a bug report, they are generally fixed fairly quickly these days

Comment: I am learning at `C++ primer` book, I meet the same problem when I practice the `variadic template`  in `vs2017`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An internal compiler error is always a bug in the compiler, whether or not there
is anything wrong with your code. To work around this one, you can replace:

```
template<int I, typename T, typename U, typename ...Rest>
struct find_type< I, T, U, Rest... >
{
    // problematic line for compiler, problem is somewhere in find_type recursion
    static constexpr int value = std::is_same<T, U>::value ? I : find_type<I + 1, T, Rest...>::value;
};
```

with:

```
template<int I, typename T, typename U, typename V, typename ...Rest>
struct find_type< I, T, U, V, Rest... >
{
    static constexpr int value = std::is_same<T, U>::value ? I : find_type<I + 1, T, V, Rest...>::value;
};
```

to assist VC++ in disambiguating it from:

```
template<int I, typename T, typename U>
struct find_type< I, T, U >
{
    static constexpr int value = std::is_same<T, U>::value ? I : -1;
};
```

when `...Rest` is empty.

[Live demo](https://rextester.com/KGWKDT28205)

Comment: Thank you very much for your idea, I have tested it and it works very well with all compilers. I will use your solution. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm getting an internal compiler error "fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.".

So, I suppose, your code is correct but the compiler is bugged.

> I'm looking for some workaround or maybe an error in my code.

I don't have your compiler, so it's a shoot in the dark, but I propose to rewrite your `find_type` struct using another specialization (a specialization for `U` and `T` are the same type; a specialization for `U` and `T` are different) and inherit the `value` from `std::integral_constant`.

So I propose the following

```
   template <int, typename ...>
   struct find_type;

   template <int I, typename T>
   struct find_type<I, T> : public std::integral_constant<int, -1>
    { };

   template <int I, typename T, typename ... Rest>
   struct find_type<I, T, T, Rest...> : public std::integral_constant<int, I>
    { };

   template <int I, typename T, typename U, typename ... Rest>
   struct find_type<I, T, U, Rest...> : public find_type<I+1, T, Rest...>
    { };
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your idea, I have tested it and get the same results as the original solution. Clang OK, gcc Ok, msvc compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible alternative is pass through a template function, instead of a `find_type` struct.

By example... if you define a `static constexpr` method `find_type_func()` as follows (C++17, but I can easily adapt it to C++14 if you want)

```
   template <typename T, typename ... List>
   constexpr static int find_type_func ()
    {
      int ret { -1 };
      int i   { 0 };

      ((ret = (ret == -1) && std::is_same<T, List>{} ? i : ret, ++i), ...);

      return ret;
    }
```

you can delete the `struct find_type` and initialize `value` as follows

```
static constexpr int value = find_type_func<Type, Types...>();
```

**-- EDIT --**

As asked, a C++14 version

```
   template <typename T, typename ... List>
   constexpr static int find_type_func ()
    {
      using unused = int[];

      int ret { -1 };
      int i   { 0 };

      (void)unused { 0, (std::is_same<T, List>::value ? ret = i : ++i)... };

      return ret;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your idea, I have tested it, but it works only with clang compiler. Anyway, I would like to see also the c++14 version, if you will be so kind and share it, maybe it will work. Inspired by @Mike Kinghan, [live demo](https://rextester.com/CNRY89141)

Comment: @MZPRX - Only clang? Really? Doesn't works also with gcc? Anyway: C++14 example added. But following your live demo, I see errors that (if I'm not wrong) show that vc is compiling C++11. By example: "'ret': declaration is not allowed in 'constexpr' function body". Variable declaration support in `constexpr` functions is introduced starting from C++14. You have to be sure of the exact version of the standard you're using.